# Some broken image links in one browser but all broken in others

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have an image gallery composed of individual albums. All files and images are loaded to the site via single function which just loops through the files passed from the form via a standard html , so every file is loaded in the same way but just put in an appropriate folder.

The gallery was working fine until last night when 4 images loaded to one album would not display.  This was traced to file permissions where the server suddenly assigned 600 rather than 644 (no permission assignments are made in the load function or anywhere else).  Correcting the permissions resulted in the images displaying.  However it was then found that a number of images in other albums were not displaying, whereas they had before.  There were no issues with permissions.

Gallery page from Edge Chromium

[image: Gallery page from Edge Chromium]

So in the album page, the first album has a broken link and the second and third are OK, the forth is broken. The display is generated from a loop going through a table of the album metadata and picking up an image at random to display for each album. For the first two albums on the page the html from looking at the page source is,

```html
<div > 
<a href="media.php?mode=grid&album=18&activity_id=17"> 
<img src="media/A18-uke.JPG" width="210px" height="140px"> 
</a> 
Altered Images - Cheryll Yeowell 
</div> 

<div > 
<a href="media.php?mode=grid&album=17&activity_id=17"> 
<img src="media/A17-IMG_0322_edited-1a.jpg" width="210px" height="140px"> 
</a> 
Chihuly at Kew - Liz Strange 
</div>
```

If I look at the files in the media folder, both the image files are in there and from Filezilla I can view them, so the images are valid.  The Filezilla folder listing shows both files the same as in the html above.

Filezilla listing of image files

[image: Filezilla listing of image files]

The file names are the same as in the html above and both have permissions of 644; one is displaying and one not.

Out of interest I then looked at the page in Firefox and Chrome.  None of the images displayed in those browsers.

Everything was working fine 3 days ago.  No changes to scripts.  Today, in Edge, some albums are fine, some only partially work, some not at all.  Move to Chrome and Firefox and nothing now works. It's not involved html and, since it is all done in loops, every image is subject to the same code.  One user has said that if there are some images showing and then the page is refreshed, all the image links display as broken, but I have not been able to replicate that.

I would welcome another set of eyes to either tell me what the silly mistake is or some inspiration as to what might be causing this apparent illogical behaviour.

Many thanks.

This is totally crazy - I am on my laptop and went to try the gallery on Edge, Firefox and Chrome and it all works perfectly.  I haven't had any updates on close down over the past two days on my laptop or desktop and I've just checked the update logs and that doesn't show any.  Since originally posting this I've had some more reports of problems from users.  How can a facility be so apparently random in its working?

Just to make it more bizarre, today everything is back to normal.  I haven't touched the code and all is back to how it should be.  What would cause a set of image links to be broken (no other links on the site were broken to my knowledge) in a random fashion for 24 hours and then revert to being OK?